# Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In Pandas, I am doing:

```
bp = p_df.groupby('class').plot(kind='kde')
```

`p_df` is a `dataframe` object.

However, this is producing two plots, one for each class.
How do I force one plot with both classes in the same plot?

Answer (score 97):

### Version 1:

You can create your axis, and then use the `ax` keyword of [`DataFrameGroupBy.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) to add everything to these axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": [1,1,2,2,1], "a": [2,3,2,3,2]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
bp = p_df.groupby('class').plot(kind='kde', ax=ax)
```

This is the result:

[image: plot]

Unfortunately, the labeling of the legend does not make too much sense here.

### Version 2:

Another way would be to loop through the groups and plot the curves manually:

```
classes = ["class 1"] * 5 + ["class 2"] * 5
vals = [1,3,5,1,3] + [2,6,7,5,2]
p_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": classes, "vals": vals})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for label, df in p_df.groupby('class'):
    df.vals.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax, label=label)
plt.legend()
```

This way you can easily control the legend. This is the result:

[image: plot2]

Answer (score 26):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p_df.groupby('class').plot(kind='kde', ax=plt.gca())
```

Answer (score 16):

Another approach would be using `seaborn` module. This would plot the two density estimates on the same axes without specifying a variable to hold the axes as follows (using some data frame setup from the other answer):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# data to create an example data frame
classes = ["c1"] * 5 + ["c2"] * 5
vals = [1,3,5,1,3] + [2,6,7,5,2]
# the data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame({"cls": classes, "indices":idx, "vals": vals})

# this is to plot the kde
sns.kdeplot(df.vals[df.cls == "c1"],label='c1');
sns.kdeplot(df.vals[df.cls == "c2"],label='c2');

# beautifying the labels
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('density')
plt.show()
```

This results in the following image.

[image: Resulting image from the code given above.]

Answer (score 7):

- There are two easy methods to plot each group in the same plot.

  1. When using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, the column to be plotted, (e.g. the aggregation column) should be specified.
  2. Use `seaborn.kdeplot` or `seaborn.displot` and specify the `hue` parameter
- Using `pandas v1.2.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, `seaborn 0.11.1`
- The OP is specific to plotting the `kde`, but the steps are the same for many plot types (e.g. `kind='line'`, `sns.lineplot`, etc.).

### Imports and Sample Data

- For the sample data, the groups are in the `'kind'` column, and the `kde` of `'duration'` will be plotted, ignoring `'waiting'`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

# display(df.head())
   duration  waiting   kind
0     3.600       79   long
1     1.800       54  short
2     3.333       74   long
3     2.283       62  short
4     4.533       85   long
```

### Plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- Reshape the data using `.groupby` or `.pivot`

#### [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

- Specify the aggregation column, `['duration']`, and `kind='kde'`.

```py
ax = df.groupby('kind')['duration'].plot(kind='kde', legend=True)
```

#### [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```py
ax = df.pivot(columns='kind', values='duration').plot(kind='kde')
```

### Plot with [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

- Specify `hue='kind'`

```py
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='duration', hue='kind')
```

### Plot with [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot)

- Specify `hue='kind'` and `kind='kde'`

```py
fig = sns.displot(data=df, kind='kde', x='duration', hue='kind')
```

### Plot

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
classes = list(df.class.unique())
for c in classes:
    df2 = data.loc[data['class'] == c]
    df2.vals.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax, label=c)
plt.legend()
```