# Drawing 3D points on a 2D plot reading values from a file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file containing sets of points with 3 coordinates, separated by tabs. Like this (spaces added for readability, not present in the original file):

```
x0 \t y0 \t z0
x0 \t y1 \t z1
x1 \t y0 \t z0
x1 \t y1 \t z1
x1 \t y2 \t z2
x2 \t y0 \t z0
...
```

I'd like to plot them as separate lines on a single 2D plot, like:

```
line for all points with x=x0, label=x0
line for all points with x=x1, label=x1
line for all points with x=x2, label=x2
```

Painting those lines with a different color.

I know numpy has a cool function for reading columns, like this:

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt(input_file, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
Y = my_data[:, 1]
Z = my_data[:, 2]
```

Is there a similarly quick and clean way of picking column values based on the value of another column?

If there's not quick function to do that (compose a column based on the x value next to it) I can parse the file and build the data structure step by step.

Then I would do something like this, using Matplotlib:

```
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlabel('Y')
ax.set_ylabel('Z')

# for each value of X
    # pick Y and Z values
    plt.plot(Y, Z, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='b', label='x_val')
```

But I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way of doing that. Maybe some trick with list comprehension?

EDIT: here's the full working code (thanks to the people who answered). I just need a way to make it show without cutting the legend

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_file = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/sturaroa/Documents/my_file.tsv')

# read values from file, by column
my_data = np.genfromtxt(input_file, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
X = my_data[:, 0]  # 1st column
Y = my_data[:, 1]  # 2nd column
Z = my_data[:, 2]  # 3rd column

# read the unique values in X and use them as keys in a dictionary of line properties
d = {val: {'label': 'x {}'.format(val), 'linestyle': '--', 'marker': 'o'} for val in set(X)}

# draw a different line for each of the unique values in X
for val, kwargs in d.items():
    mask = X == val
    y, z = Y[mask], Z[mask]
    plt.plot(y, z, **kwargs)

# label the axes of the plot
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlabel('Y')
ax.set_ylabel('Z')

# get the labels of all the lines in the graph
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# create a legend growing it from the middle and put it on the right side of the graph
lgd = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

# save the figure so that the legend fits inside it
plt.savefig('my_file.pdf', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You might like the pandas library; it's very good at sorting and grouping tabular data, and plotting the results. Here's a relevant example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a dictionary of `value:kwargs` pairs, where `value` is the value that `X` must take to be in that curve and `kwargs` is a dict that holds arguments to be passed to the plotting function.

The code below will use the `value` to construct a mask which can be used to index and choose the appropriate points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


my_data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=' ', skiprows=0)
X = my_data[:, 0]
Y = my_data[:, 1]
Z = my_data[:, 2]

d = {
    0: {'label': 'x0'},
    1: {'label': 'x1'}
}

for val, kwargs in d.items():
    mask = X == val
    y, z = Y[mask], Z[mask]

    plt.plot(y, z, **kwargs)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Better yet, initialize `d` with dict comprehensions: `d = {val: {'label': 'x' + str(val), 'linestyle': '--'} for val in np.unique(X)}`, then you can change other properties for each line in subsequent lines, e.g. `d[0]['color']='b'`, and `d[1]['color']='r'`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using dictionaries for this.  Start by loading your data,

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt(input_file, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
X = my_data[:, 0]
Y = my_data[:, 1]
Z = my_data[:, 2]
```

Then create a dictionary with the arrays for each value of x:

```
Ydict = {}
Zdict = {}
for x in np.unique(X):
    inds = X == x
    Ydict[x] = Y[inds]
    Zdict[x] = Z[inds]
```

Now you have two dictionaries with keys that are the unique values of `X` (note the use of `np.unique`), and the values of the dictionaries are the arrays where `X` matches the key.

Your plot call would then look something like,

```
for x in Ydict:
    plt.plot(Ydict[x], Zdict[x], label=str(x), ...)
```

You'll want to replace the `...` with whatever other line properties you want to set, but if you want each line to be a different color don't use `color='b'`.

Does that help?