# Plot view/click stream for several messages

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have some information with dates on views and clicks on several messages.  I'd like to plot view and clicks rounded by hours.

I've coerced data to such DataFrame:

```
sl = pd.DataFrame({'index':sendlog.index,
               'idMessage': sendlog['idMessage'], 
               'View': pd.to_datetime(sendlog['dtFirstView']).apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0)), 
               'Click': pd.to_datetime(sendlog['dtFirstClick']).apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))},
               columns=('idMessage', 'View', 'Click')
)
```

`sl.head(5)` shows:

```
    idMessage   View            Click
0   728403  2016-12-12 05:00:00 NaT
1   728403  2016-12-12 02:00:00 NaT
2   727895  2016-12-12 15:00:00 NaT
3   727918  2016-11-30 09:00:00 2016-11-30 09:00:00
4   727895  2016-11-30 12:00:00 NaT
```

Some messages aren't clicked - there're `NaT` values.

I want to see a plot with a histogram for every message with number of views and clicks in every hour.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas) a similar question, but it's grouped only in one dimension.

If I groupby them and count size of each group I can't plot them as, because I got a `numpy.int64` object as a result.

How to better plot such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a way of doing it

```
sl_ = sl.set_index('idMessage')
cliks = sl_.Click.dropna()
# I want the Timestamps in the index so I can use pd.TimeGrouper
cliks = pd.Series(cliks.index.values, cliks.values)
views = sl_.View.dropna()
# I want the Timestamps in the index so I can use pd.TimeGrouper
views = pd.Series(views.index.values, views.values)

view_count = views.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('H'), views]).count().rename('View')
clik_count = cliks.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('H'), cliks]).count().rename('Click')

pd.concat([view_count, clik_count], axis=1).query('View >= 1 and Click >= 1')
```

[image]