# Pandas dataframe groupby plot (extension)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask you about an extension of the post "[Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas)". Such an extension comes into play when we apply the function '`groupby`' more than once. Specifically, I am interested in plotting this function. I am dealing with the line below, which is incompatible with the function plot.

Line:

```
f=s['Amount'].groupby([s['classe'],s['Month'],s['Year']]).sum()
```

which sums over 'Amount' and groups 'classe', 'Month' and 'Year'. For simplicity let 'Year' be always the same value: 2017.

Now I would like to make the following plot:

- Plot 'Month vs Amount' for a specific type of 'classe'

My attempt:

```
for label, df in s.groupby('classe').get_group('Rent'):
      df.plot.scatter(x='Month', y='Amount', s=50)
plt.show()
```

where Rent represents the specific above-mentioned 'classe'. This attempt does not work and does not take into consideration the sum over 'Amount'. I was not able to use such a '`sum()`' together with the function plot. Clearly, these lines without `get_group('Rent')` give me as many plots as the number of classes. They do not count over 'Amount' yet. Any ideas/suggestions?

I also tried to use `pivot_table` as you can see in the following code. I can plot all together but I can not plot a single class. Here my attempt:

```
test=pd.pivot_table(s,index=['classe','Month','Year'],values=['Amount'],aggfunc=np.sum)
test.unstack('classe').unstack('Year').plot(kind='area', figsize,[16,6],stacked=False,colormap='autumn').legend(loc=2,prop={'size':9}) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions or good examples? I would like to understand how to plot whatever I want from these `pivot_table` and `groupby` functions.

Comment: Edit queue is full so I can't add it, but looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas) is the question you're referring to?

Comment: I have read it but it was not my case. There 'groupby' is used only once: p_df.groupby('class'). In my case I would like to group by several columns: 'classe', 'Month', 'Year' :(

Comment: Gotcha, I was just linking it to save someone the time to look it up. I was able to suggest an edit just now adding that and updating your tags, so hopefully someone with more pandas knowledge will see it! If it is Python version-specific feel free to [edit] the version tag back in.

Answer (score 0):

Consider filtering by each unique *Classe* that loops through your current `pivot_table` and `unstack` routine. Below demonstrates with positive number random data which should always reproduce the same by defined seeds:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(176)
random.seed(16)

df = pd.DataFrame({'classe': random.sample(list('ABCDE')*50, k=15),
                   'Amount': np.random.sample(15)*100,
                   'Year': random.sample(list(range(2010,2018))*50, k=15),
                   'Month': random.sample(list(range(1,12))*50, k=15)})

for cls in df['classe'].unique(): 
    # AREA GRAPH
    test = pd.pivot_table(df[df['classe']==cls], index=['classe', 'Month', 'Year'], values=['Amount'], aggfunc=np.sum)
    test.unstack('classe').unstack('Year').plot(kind='area', figsize=(16,6), stacked=False, colormap='autumn').legend(loc=2,prop={'size':9}) 

    # SCATTER PLOT
    test = pd.pivot_table(df[df['classe']==cls], index=['classe', 'Month', 'Year'], values=['Amount'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()    
    test.plot(kind='scatter', x='Month',y='Amount', figsize=(16,6), stacked=False).legend(loc=2,prop={'size':9})
    plt.show() 

plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

Area Graph Outputs

[image: Class A Graph]
[image: Class B Graph]
[image: Class C Graph]
[image: Class D Graph]
[image: Class E Graph]

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear! Last question. If I wanted obtain a scatter plot instead of a 'area' kind plot, what could I modify the code? The following code:  "test.unstack('classe').unstack('Year').plot.scatter(x='Month',y='Amount', figsize=(16,6), stacked=False, colormap='autumn').legend(loc=2,prop={'size':9})"  
gives me the error "KeyError: Month"... Thanks in advaced

Comment: You don't need an `unstack` method. Simply run `pivot_table` with a `reset_index()` to get *Month* as a level 0 column instead of hierarchical level 1. Then run scatter. See edit. Do note *colormap* is removed.

Comment: Thanks very much. I would like to summarize all the info I get in only one scatter plot. is it possible by using this iterative method? better with different colors. Moreover, if I use your code and wanna see a particular writing on each scatter plot, how can I do it? Many thanks @Parfait

Comment: These sound like a new question. Please accept this one (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.

Comment: Yes as it strays from this question.