# Loop and plot GroupBy data with fixed axes in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

(**In a Jupyter Notebook**): I'd like to loop through the groups in a Pandas Groupby Object and plot their GPS coordinate on the same axes. First, I'd like to clear the figure each time and plot solely the data by group. In a second case, I'd like for them to accumulate and not be cleared.

Question 1: Unfortunately in the code below, the axes change every iteration. Anyone know how to keep the axes fixed?

Question 2: How do I keep vs clear iterations?

This is my starter code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('LON'); ax.set_ylabel('LAT')
ax.set_xlim(50, 100); ax.set_ylim(0 ,30)
plt.ion()

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

for key, data in groups:
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(data.LON, data.LAT)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas is a similar question. Personally, I prefer the second answer, since it's easier to label. However, when I tried it, I couldn't get the colors to be correctly labeled in the scatter plot, so you might need a manual loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas)