# Pandas values back in time when plotting them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some IDs and for each ID I have a timestamp and a value associated. I need to make all the IDs start from 0 and plot them together to see differences, so I used this code:

```
df['Date']=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

To substitute the Date columns with indexes going from 0 to the last row number of that specific ID. Now, my problem is that the result of the normal plot is this one, with lines going back in time and I can't understand why

[image]

Another image:
[image]

As you can see, that is not possible but I don't understand how to fix this. Basically, I'm plotting all the values in both dataframes for each ID and for the newly created time.
After that, I need to perform statistical analysis on them, like create rolling mean or variance, and a gaussian distribution over the dataframes.
How can I fix this?

Edit:
here's my dataframe:

```
ID      Date                           value
12345    2017-02-09 14:35:00               60.0
12345    2017-02-09 14:40:00               62.0
12345    2017-02-09 14:45:00               58.0
12345    2017-02-09 14:50:00               60.0
54321    2017-03-09 13:35:00               50.0 
54321    2017-03-09 13:40:00               58.0 
54321    2017-03-09 13:45:00               59.0 
54321    2017-03-09 13:50:00               61.0
```

I would need to reshape the Date column and start everything from 0, with the command above, and the below result:

```
ID      timestamp       value
12345    0               60.0
12345    1               62.0
12345    2               58.0
12345    3               60.0
54321    0               50.0 
54321    1               58.0 
54321    2               59.0 
54321    3               61.0
```

edit2: if I try with the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for label, df in p_df.groupby('ID'):
    df.vals.plot(kind="line", ax=ax, label=label)
plt.legend()
```

the compiler keep building but doesn't print anything.
And how do I confront two dataframes in this way?

Comment: Looks like you want to plot a separate line for each `ID`, as when the cumcount resets, the line is connected all the way from the right to the left. You can iterate through the `groupby` and plot everything on the same `ax`

Comment: How can I do that? Do I need a for loop?

Comment: Either a loop over the groups, or reshape the data so that you have one column per group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas shows how to do it both ways.

Comment: yes, but how do I modify the Date value to start from 0 everytime for each ID?

Comment: It will automatically because of `cumcount`. Otherwise, you need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem, because all I can do is guess, and SO isn't really the place for extended conversations through comments.

Comment: I'm modifying the post with some of my datas

Comment: added some examples