# unstacking in a pandas dataframe and plotting the results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `df` like this:

```
     algo   pairings        mean       stdev
0   algo1          1    0.289224    0.109537
1   algo1          3    0.301253    0.024995
2   algo1          4    0.323887    0.041857
3   algo2          1    0.289440    0.018899
4   algo2          3    0.296124    0.023745
...
```

and I'd like to plot different lines for each "algorithm" mean in `algo`, and the error bars using `stdev`. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
df.unstack('algo').plot(yerr="stdev")
```

It tells me `KeyError: 'Requested level (algo) does not match index name (None)'`

Comment: maybe `df.groupby('algo').plot(yerr='stdev')`

Comment: after unstacking df.unstack('algo') there is no column "stdev" and df.unstack('algo') works you withhout error? For me yes.

Comment: This should do the trick for you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28299215/11221013