# How to plot/scatter geo coordinates in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having a hard time plotting something in pandas the way I want it.

I have movement traces in a csv file that look like that:

```
NodeID | Time   | Lon              | Lat             # Line not in the CSV
0      | 38.665 |29564.86465677584 |37278.27065254189
0      | 64.29  |29529.86419382295 |37300.74058444612
0      | 80.74  |29511.18207467592 |37317.11012177728
1      | 166.3  |29593.54098394629 |37403.83872184437
1      | 188.98 |29622.25878085964 |37441.86538931914
1      | 219.33 |29658.04716892622 |37491.65280349273
.
.
.
20     | 566.3  |29593.54098394629 |37403.83872184437
20     | 888.98 |29622.25878085964 |37441.86538931914
30     | 919.33 |29658.04716892622 |37491.65280349273
```

I read the csv with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=' ', 
                 names=["node", "time", "x","y"], header=None)
```

Now I want to plot every node with a different color. Ideally, every point should be connected to the next, but this is not necessary due to the close distance of the locations.

I tried it with:

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
# or
df[NodeID:].plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
# or with matplotlib
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(pddata['x'], pddata['y'], label='node ' + str(pddata['node']))
```

But it always looks like this:

[image: Plot of coordinates]

Can someone give me a hint how to plot it the way I want it?

Comment: Your x coordinate should represent longitude, not latitude.

Comment: It is right in the csv. Mixed it up in the question. Fixed it now. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want the colors to be assigned? Randomly from a set of colors? Using a color map? Is there a grouping you are going off of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas)

Comment: @Ben.T Did not solve it. Now every Node gets it own window. I want them all in one plot. Colors can be random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the `seaborn` package, it can be quite helpful in plotting and works with `pandas`. Looking through its gallery as well as the python graph gallery the might also give some inspiration for your plots.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/
https://python-graph-gallery.com/

For your specific problem, with the dataframe set up, this hopefully helps:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='x', y='y', hue='node', marker='o', data=df)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I found an other way. Since I'm more comftable with matplotlip and I'ts plotting freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution thankts to some tipps in the comments.

Now i use matplotlip to plot and pandas to group:

```
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 15), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.subplots()

df = pd.read_csv('Filename', delimiter=' ', names=["node", "time", "x","y"], header=None)

# Scatter for every node
for node, node_data in df.groupby('node'):
    ax.scatter(node_data['x'], node_data['y'], label='node ' + str(node), s=2,
    c=np.random.rand(3,))
    #or use ax.plot to show lines

plt.show()
```