# Creating a time-series plot with data in long format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have time-series data in a pandas `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
ID  HeartRate
1      120
1      118
1      115
2      98
2      110
2      112
3      128
3      115
3      90
```

And I want to create a separate line plot for each of the distinct IDs (i.e. patients). How can I go about this preferably using matplotlib? Will I have to create a "time-interval" variable?

---

```py
df = my_data[['ID', 'HR']].copy() ## creating a new "mini" dataframe from the larger one that I've got. 

n_ids = df.ID.unique().size 
n_cols = int(n_ids ** 0.5) 
n_rows = int(n_ids + n_ids % n_cols) 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols) 
for i, (ids, hr) in enumerate(df.groupby('ID')['HR']): 
hr.plot(ax=axes[i], title=f"ID:{idx}") 
fig.tight_layout()
```

However, as I get the following error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

Comment: are you open to using the `pandas` library?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to mention that my data set has been imported as pandas dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas)

Comment: By separate you mean each ID on a different `ax`?

Comment: I don't think that it does because from what I can tell they are plotting the different distinct units on a single plot there and what I am looking to do is the contrary (unless I've missed something in the thread!)

Comment: By separate I mean each ID in a separate plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `groupby` and plot it:

```
df.groupby('ID')['HeartRate'].plot()
```

Or using multiple axes, without worrying (so much at least) with the size of the category:

```
n_ids = df.ID.unique().size
n_cols = int(n_ids ** 0.5)
n_rows = n_cols + (1 if n_ids % n_cols else 0)                   
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
axes = axes.ravel()
for i, (idx, series) in enumerate(df.groupby('ID')['HeartRate']):
    series.plot(ax=axes[i], title=f"ID:{idx}")
fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But running this code, all the line graphs are in the sample plot. I am instead trying to create a distinct plot for each distinct ID.

Comment: No, I added a one-ID per-plot version.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was going for - sorry I might have missed that chunk of code the first time around. However, when I run the code I get the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' - any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you post the exact code? You are likely mixing an array with an axe. Anyway why would want to `get_figure` if you already have it in the code I showed you?

Comment: It'll work if you do `axes[0].get_figure()` for example.

Comment: This what I've done (I've also added to the original question so its clearer)
df = my_data[['ID', 'HR']].copy() 
## creating a new "mini" dataframe from the larger one that I've got.
n_ids = df.ID.unique().size
n_cols = int(n_ids ** 0.5)
n_rows = int(n_ids + n_ids % n_cols)                   
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
for i, (ids, hr) in enumerate(df.groupby('ID')['HR']):
    hr.plot(ax=axes[i], title=f"ID:{idx}")
    fig.tight_layout()