# Python Plotting Grouped Data

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pandas-groupby

The grouped data looks like

[image: The Grouped Data looks like]

My approach yields to

[image]

I'd want a result like

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide data. Don't share the data as a pic.

Comment: [Group again by MAPPING, then plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28293028/8881141) or use seaborn or pivot MAPPING into distinct columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the test DataFrame I used:

```
         MAPPING CREATED_DTM  counts
0  Beschaedigung  2020-04-30   22738
1  Beschaedigung  2020-05-31   21523
2  Beschaedigung  2020-06-30   18516
3  Beschaedigung  2020-07-31   21436
4  Beschaedigung  2020-08-31   22325
5        Verlust  2020-04-30   20000
6        Verlust  2020-05-31   19500
7        Verlust  2020-06-30   22400
8        Verlust  2020-07-31   19100
9        Verlust  2020-08-31   21100
```

(*CREATED_DTM* column of *datetime64[ns]* type).

An elegant solution to create the plot you want, is to use *seaborn*.

Start from necessary imports:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
```

Then, run:

```
sns.lineplot(data=reaktiv_mapping, x='CREATED_DTM', y='counts', hue='MAPPING')
ax = plt.gca()
x = ax.xaxis
x.set_major_locator(md.MonthLocator())
x.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0));
```

For the above source data, I got the following plot:

[image]

To get the grid, like in your expected picture, you can start with:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
```

Comment: you are an angel, thank you very much!